# Text file to spreadsheet

Tags: python, excel

Lets say you have several .txt files in a folder and want to merge all text files into a single Excel document:

**A.txt**

```
A1
A2
A3
A4
A5
A6
A7
A8
A9
A10
A11
A12
A13
A14
A15
A16
A17
A18
A19
A20
A21
A22
```

**B.txt**

```
B1
B2
B3
B4
B5
B6
B7
B8
B9
B10
B11
B12
B13
B14
```

**C.txt**

```
C1
C2
C3
C4
C5
C6
C7
C8
C9
C10
C11
C12
C13
C14
C15
C16
C17
C18
C19
C20
C21
C22
C23
C24
C25
C26
C27
C28
C29
C30
C31
C32
C33
```

**D.txt**

```
//empty file
```

**E.txt**

```
E1
E2
E3
E4
E5
E6
E7
E8
E9
E10
E11
E12
E13
E14
E15
E16
E17
E18
E19
E20
E21
E22
E23
E24
E25
E26
E27
E28
E29
E30
E31
E32
E33
E34
E35
E36
E37
E38
```

**The Output:**

[image]

**spreadsheet_to_text.py**

```
"""
Reads all .txt files in path of the script into a single
spreadsheet. In the first line of the spreadsheet the filename were
the data is from is displayed. Then the data follows
"""

import os
from typing import List
import openpyxl
from openpyxl.utils import get_column_letter

def text_into_spreadsheet():
    """main logic for read .txt into spreadsheet"""
    workbook = openpyxl.Workbook()
    sheet = workbook.active
    column: int = 1
    filenames: List[str] = os.listdir()
    for filename in filenames:
        if filename.endswith(".txt"):
            with open(filename) as textfile:
                lines: List[int] = textfile.readlines()
                sheet[get_column_letter(column) + '1'] = filename
                row: int = 2
                for line in lines:
                    sheet[get_column_letter(column) + str(row)] = line
                    row += 1
            column += 1
    workbook.save('result.xlsx')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    text_into_spreadsheet()
```

What do you think about the code?
How can it be improved?

edit: you can find a programm doing it in reversed in [Spreadsheets to text files](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/210000/spreadsheets-to-text-files)

Comment: Does it *have* to be an Excel spreadsheet, or can it simply be importable by Excel? If the latter, you really should output to something like CSV, which will be faster and simpler.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are a few things we could improve:

- you could use the "lazy" [`glob.iglob()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html#glob.iglob) to filter out `*.txt` files instead of doing the `os.listdir()`, keeping the whole list if memory and having an extra check inside the loop:

  ```
  for filename in glob.iglob("*.txt"):
  ```
- instead of using `textfile.readlines()` and read all the lines in a file into memory, iterate over the file object directly in a *"lazy" manner*:

  ```
  for line in textfile:
  ```
- instead of manually keeping track of `column` value, you could use [`enumerate()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate):

  ```
  for column, filename in enumerate(glob.iglob("*.txt"), start=1):
  ```

  Same idea could be applied for rows.
- I think you don't have to use `get_column_letter()` and instead operate the numbers which you have:

  ```
  sheet.cell(row=row, column=column).value = line
  ```
- not to say anything against `openpyxl`, but I personally find [`xlsxwriter`](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/) module's API more enjoyable and more feature rich

---

Complete improved version:

```
import glob

import openpyxl


def text_into_spreadsheet():
    """main logic for read .txt into spreadsheet"""
    workbook = openpyxl.Workbook()
    sheet = workbook.active

    for column, filename in enumerate(glob.iglob("*.txt"), start=1):
        with open(filename) as textfile:
            sheet.cell(row=1, column=column).value = filename

            for row, line in enumerate(textfile, start=2):
                sheet.cell(row=row, column=column).value = line

    workbook.save('result.xlsx')


if __name__ == "__main__":
    text_into_spreadsheet()
```

Comment: I think this solution is very very nice. It is alot better to read compared to what i did.

Answer (score 4):

If you're on a Linux/Mac machine, it's as simple as this shell command:

```
paste ?.txt
```

The `?` wildcard will match all your files, `A.txt` to `E.txt` in order. The `paste` command will paste them in parallel columns, separated by TABs.

You can then open your spreadsheet app and import the text file, and add the header.

Per a question formerly in comments: Can you auto-generate the header as well? 
Sure:

```
for f in ?.txt; do echo -en "$f\t"; done; echo; paste ?.txt
```

Also, I'm assuming a single letter before `.txt`, as in the original example. If you want *all* files ending in `.txt`, then it's `*.txt` instead of `?.txt`.