# Migrating data from multiple spreadsheets to multiple text files

Tags: python, python-3.x, excel

This is like the reverse functionality of [Text file to spreadsheet](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/209933/text-file-to-spreadsheet).

One or multiple `.xlsx` files in the path of the script get opened and the content is split into multiple `.txt` files.

For example, say you have two excel files in the folder:

**file1.xlsx**

[image]

**file2.xlsx**

[image]

**The output created:**

[image]
[image]
[image]

[image]
[image]
[image]

**spreadsheet_to_text.py**

```
"""
Reads in .xlsx files from path were the script is located.
Then the data of each column is split into a .txt file
"""

import glob
import openpyxl
from openpyxl.utils import get_column_letter

def get_text_filename(filename: str, column: int)->str:
    """
    Creates a text filename based on .xlsx file filename and column
    """
    return (filename.rstrip(".xlsx")
            + "_" + get_column_letter(column) + '.txt')


def xlsx_to_txt(filename: str):
    """
    Extract data from a .xlsx file in the script folder into
    multiple .txt files
    """
    workbook = openpyxl.load_workbook(filename)
    sheet_names = workbook.sheetnames
    sheet = workbook[sheet_names[0]]

    for column in range(1, sheet.max_column + 1):
        if sheet.cell(row=1, column=column).value:
            text_filename = get_text_filename(filename, column)
            with open(text_filename, mode='w') as textfile:
                for row in range(1, sheet.max_row + 1):
                    if sheet.cell(column=column, row=row).value:
                        textfile.writelines(
                            sheet.cell(column=column, row=row).value + '\n')


def spreadsheet_into_text():
    """main logic for split spreadsheet data into multiple text files"""
    for filename in glob.iglob("*.xlsx"):
        xlsx_to_txt(filename)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    spreadsheet_into_text()
```

I already incorporated some improvements from [Text file to spreadsheet](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/209933/text-file-to-spreadsheet). I wonder how the code can get further improved.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This looks quite clean in general. May I suggest a few minor improvements:

- I think you could just use `workbook.active` to get the sheet
- instead of doing the `rstrip(".xlsx")` which would also right-strip out `.sslsx` or `sl.xs.ss` and even grab a part of the actual filename:

  ```
  In [1]: "christmas.xlsx".rstrip(".xlsx")
  Out[1]: 'christma'
  ```

  use [`os` module or the beautiful `pathlib` to properly extract a filename without an extension](https://stackoverflow.com/q/678236/771848):

  ```
  In [1]: from pathlib import Path

  In [2]: Path("christmas.xlsx").resolve().stem
  Out[2]: 'christmas'
  ```
- calculate what you can before the loop instead of inside it. For instance, `sheet.max_row` is something you could just remember in a variable at the top of your function and re-use inside. It's not a lot of savings, but *[attribute access still has its cost in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28597014/python-why-is-accessing-instance-attribute-is-slower-than-local)*:

  ```
  max_row = sheet.max_row
  ```
- something similar is happening when you get the value of a cell twice, instead:

  ```
  cell_value = sheet.cell(column=column, row=row).value

  if cell_value:
      textfile.writelines(cell_value + '\n')
  ```
- it may be a good idea to keep the nestedness at a minimum (["Flat is better than nested."](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/)) and would rather check for a reverse condition and use `continue` to move to the next iteration:

  ```
  for column in range(1, sheet.max_column + 1):
      if not sheet.cell(row=1, column=column).value:
          continue

      text_filename = get_text_filename(filename, column)
  ```

**Some out-of-the-box ideas:**

- feels like if you do it with [`pandas.read_excel()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_excel.html#pandas-read-excel) it may just become way more easier and beautiful

Comment: thanks for the high quality answer. I really liked how it simplyfies the code. One little thing. I think in the question i already use `writelines` instead of `write` ?